# Uso Text User Interfaces no C#?

Tags: c#, .net, console

Gostaria dar uma interface básica a um aplicativo desenvolvido em Console Application. Quero fazer uso de recursos como TUI (Text-Based User Interfaces), comuns em outras plataformas como NodeJS. É possível fazer isso em uma aplicação C#?

Exemplo:

[image: TUI]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, é possível, só dá trabalho. Algumas pessoas já criaram bibliotecas para eliminar boa parte do trabalho, entre elas:

- [Terminal GUI](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/gui.cs)
- [Console Framework](https://github.com/elw00d/consoleframework)
- [Console Draw](https://github.com/Haydend/ConsoleDraw)
- [SharpTUI](https://github.com/aaronhance/SharpTUI)
- [TUI](http://tui.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest) ([alternativa](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/CSharp_Free_Code/ComboBox/Download_TUI_a_Text_User_Interface_Windows_Library_for_net.htm) se o *link* morrer)
- [Console Objects](https://github.com/skthomasjr/ConsoleObjects)
- [Curses Sharp](http://curses-sharp.sourceforge.net/)

Não as usei então não sei se são boas ou mantidas.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).